# Example code for Stripe Connect [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments

Is there an example code/documentation for Stripe Connect that handle business onboarding/registration for flutter application?

I can't find it on the package documentation [flutter_stripe](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe)

Answer (score 0):

Stipe is simplest way to integrate payment gateway solution.

Here is a tutorial to implement this. [LINK](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/stripe-payment-in-flutter-d7f87f9a193c)

When you go onboard just need to change the api keys and code will remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

you can call Stripe API to create an account link (see [doc](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts#create-link)), and open the account link's [URL](https://stripe.com/docs/api/account_links/object#account_link_object-url) in a Webview inside your Flutter application.

However, I think it's better to let your user experience the onboarding flow in a keyboard friendly environment such as desktop, because they need to fill up lots of information.